# How to convert MySQL to GeoJSON?

Tags: php, mysql, geojson

I am using [This](https://github.com/bmcbride/PHP-Database-GeoJSON) GitHub repository, as linked elsewhere when researching how to achieve my goal, in order to convert the data in my SQL database to GeoJSON. Previously I had a basic geojson file with lat,long points and it works independently. However I am having immense trouble getting this individual's PHP scripts to work. Below are my attempts at implementing their code.

The loadMap function, javascript debugger shows no errors here:

```
    function loadMap() {

    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
           /* attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>', */
            maxZoom: 18,
            id: 'mapbox.dark',
            accessToken: '--'
        }).addTo(mymap);

    $.getJSON("mysql_points_geojson.php",function(data){
        L.geoJson(data, {
          pointToLayer: function(feature,latlng){
            var marker = L.marker(latlng);
                    if (feature.properties) {
                    var content = '<table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;" cellpadding="2">' +
                    '<tr>' + '<th>Gender</th>' + '<td>' + feature.properties.gender + '</td>' + '</tr>' +
                    '<tr>' + '<th>Age</th>' + '<td>' + feature.properties.age + '</td>' + '</tr>' +
                    '<tr>' + '<th>Address</th>' + '<td>' + feature.properties.address + '</td>' + '</tr>' +
                    '<tr>' + '<th>Town</th>' + '<td>' + feature.properties.town + '</td>' + '</tr>' +
                    '<table>';
                    marker.bindPopup(content);
                }
            return marker;
          }
        }).addTo(mymap);    

    }
)}
```

The `mysql_points_geojson.php` located in the GitHub is what I am using, and I changed only the database login information. So that remains untouched and can be found in the GitHub. I've also based my script code off of the provided demo in the GitHub page.

I've been fiddling with this for days, and have tried just about every combination I can imagine. Attached is an image of mySQL table breakdown if needed: [SQL Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gz3yY.png)

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: It's not working and I am unsure how to proceed. Like I mentioned, JS console shows no errors. I know the SQL database works because I can access it manually. So tips on needed debug info, or notable issues that go past me are kind of what I'm looking for at the moment. Something to put me in the right direction

Comment: "It's not working" is hopelessly vague.  Please be a bit more specific: Are you failing to read ANYTHING from Mysql?  Is the MySql result set OK, but the JSON,incorrect?  Where exactly do thing "go off the rails"?  What exactly are you expecting to see instead? Etc. etc.

Comment: I don't know if the script is ever reading anything from the server. The site loads, executes the loadMap function, then it stops without ever adding any points on the map. There should be two points added - I copied the initial data from when I go the map working with a normal geojson file, so I know the data is fine. It's the transportation and conversion of said data. The console displays no errors after slight fiddling, where as before the function didn't load the map. I'm unsure where in the pipeline things are getting caught up since the debugger is empty.

Comment: Q: "I don't know if the script is ever reading anything from the server."  A: Please set a breakpoint in your "read()" handler (not shown?) and find out.  Q: What debugger are you using?  Chrome Developer Tools?  Q: is there any chance you can reproduce the problem with an [MCVE]?